# Foreach Loop Enumerator with multiple File Names

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel, visual-studio

I have a directory like `C:\NewExcelFile` in which I have lots of different Excel files with different names (but with the same extension *.xlsx*). I have a "foreach loop enumerator" in my package which I need to be executed (in each loop) at the number of Excel files which start with 'SMR' and in the next loop with 'PIR' and the next time with the 'ZFR' (for instance).

This is how I'm trying to configure the container:

[image]

but unfortunately I get this warning every time:

> Warning: The Foreach File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

How can I configure a Foreach loop container that every time has a different file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do I don't think you should put your expression in the `Directory` property.

I think you need to put:

- Your directory name (`C:\NewExcelFile\`) in as the `Directory`. If this never changes, it can be entered directly in the configuration window, instead of as an expression.
- Your filename pattern (`@[User::Name] + "*.xlsx"`) should be an expression, but should go in the `FileSpec` property

Like so:

[image]